# Type promotion of overloaded function's argument

Tags: delphi, type-promotion

Consider the following code:

```
program Promote;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

{$HINTS OFF}

type
  MyWord = record
    FValue: LongWord;
    class operator Implicit(AValue: LongWord): MyWord;
  end;

class operator MyWord.Implicit(AValue: LongWord): MyWord;
begin
  Result.FValue:= AValue;
end;

procedure Test(AValue: MyWord); overload;
begin
  Writeln('MyWord');
end;

procedure Test(AValue: UInt64); overload;
begin
  Writeln('UInt64');
end;

var
  LW: LongWord;

begin
  Test(LW);
  Readln;
end.
```

When I run it (Delphi XE) I see that the compiler promotes `LongWord` parameter to `UInt64` (built-in type), not to `MyWord` (user-defined type).

Can I assume that Delphi compiler always promotes a built-in type to a built-in type if such promotion is implemented in the compiler itself?

More generally what rules control type promotion in such situations (say we have 2 built-in types, or 2 user-defined types, etc)?

Comment: Good luck working this out. No documentation exists. The best you can do is to reverse it.

Comment: I would **expect** that it is always the **nearest** type

Comment: @Sir It's easy to write that down, but without a precise definition of nearest, what does it mean. I find it really frustrating that the rules for overload resolution are so inadequately documented.

Comment: *More generally what rules control type promotion in such situations (say we have 2 built-in types, or 2 user-defined types, etc)?* If we have two built in types, then the rules are as documented, modulo the fact that the documentation is imprecise (see discussion below Dalija's answer).  If we have two user-defined types, both available via implicit conversion operators then that is deemed to be ambiguous. If we have one intrinsic type, and one user defined type, then the intrinsic type is preferred. All this I observe by trial and error, the documentation offers nothing.

Comment: Now, one does need to clarify what intrinsic types are. I think these are the ones that are defined by the language rather than the runtime library. So, these are the types like `System.Integer` and `System.Double` that are ostensibly part of the `System` unit but are in fact built in or intrinsic to the language. I do wonder what the full list of such types is. All of this I can say from observation alone.

Comment: Compiler's first choice will always be procedure that preserves values of actual parameters passed in the call. When more than one procedure satisfies above condition following can be observed: compiler prefers built-in types over user defined and signed over unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding an ordinal type like `uint64` will always be closer to another ordinal type like `longword`, than a `record`. Period.

The "closer type" distance is not about "built-in" or "custom" types. You are comparing apples and oranges.

In the compiler, records and ordinals are two diverse families. The fact you can define implicit conversion would never promote a `record` to become an ordinal type.

As a result, a "built-in" `string` will always have less affinity with an `integer` than a new ordinal type like:

```
type TMyInteger64 = type Int46;
```

Here, this `TMyInteger64` type will be "nearer" than a built-in `string` type.

As soon as you define a `record`, it will have affinities with other `record`, not ordinal types.